# Only the last result of a for-loop iteration is being saved in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, iteration

I am very new to Python and I am currently trying to store results from a for-loop in a dictionary. I am aiming to get "ratios" as keys and "frequency" as values. I want to iterate through a list of unique ratios and count them in a dictionary called `comparison_dict`. I have done that part and to do it I first created a type list from the `comparison_dict` values (`list_orig_ratios`).

```
frequencies = dict()
sorted_unique_ratios = sorted(unique_ratios)

list_orig_ratios = list(comparison_dict.values())
for ratio in sorted_unique_ratios:
    freq = list_orig_ratios.count(ratio)
    frequencies = {ratio:freq}
    print(frequencies)
```

When I add the print command at the end of my for-loop I can see all pairs of ratios and their counts but each of them is a separate dictionary. I would like to have them all as a single dictionary, with ratios as keys and frequencies (counts) as values. If I run the print command outside of the loop I see that only the last key:value pair is saved there.

How can I store the results of this for-loop in a single dictionary?

Comment: `frequencies = {ratio:freq}` This replaces `frequencies` completely. Change to `frequencies[ratio] = freq` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a new `dict` to the name `frequencies` in each iteration, rather than adding a new key-value pair to the existing `dict`.

```
for ratio in sorted_unique_ratios:
    freq = list_orig_ratios.count(ratio)
    frequencies[ratio] = freq
    print(frequencies)
```

A simpler solution, though, is to use a dictionary comprehension:

```
frequencies = {ratio: list_orig_ratios.count(ratio) for ratio in sorted(unique_ratios)}
```